# Evento en Template String

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un problema para ejecutar un evento en el botón de un template string, he intentado con onclick pero me dice que la función allData() esta undefined, intente con EventListener pero me arroja null, pensé que era un problema de orden de ejecución del DOM y puse la etiqueta script después de la etiqueta del body, pero no he logrado mostrar el modal. Agradezco cualquier sugerencia.

```js
import data from './data/rickandmorty/rickandmorty.js';


let allCharacters = document.getElementById('allCharacters'),
  modal = document.getElementById('myModal'),
  flex = document.getElementById('flex'),
  open = document.getElementById('open'),
  close = document.getElementById('close');

window.onload = function characters() {

  let allPersonage = data.results;
  let file = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < allPersonage.length; i++) {

    file += `
               <section class="cont03">
                    <img class ="image_characters" src="${allPersonage[i].image}" alt="rick-and-morty-image">
                    <h2 class="name">${allPersonage[i].name}</h2>
                    <button onclick="allData()" class="informacion">Details</button>
               </section>`

  };

  allCharacters.innerHTML = file;

  
};

function allData() {
     if (modal.style.display = "none") {
       modal.style.display = "block";
     }
   }
```

Comment: El problema es que cuando eso se renderiza queda en un Scope global y en ese scope tu función `allData` no está definida. Si puedes definirla en el scope global con algo como `window.allData = function () { ... }` ahí si podría tener acceso.

Comment: Pon la etiqueta `<script>` **al final** del body, así no tendrás que usar `window.onload()` y el evento `onclick` podrá usar todas la funciones **ya definidas**.